# What does java program run out of memory when running in docker

Tags: java, docker

I have a java program whose only function is to use about 512M RAM and be idle.  Running natively it works:

```
java -Xmx559m MemoryEater
```

When I run the same program with the same memory settings in Docker, Java errors out with an out of memory error. That's java not docker killing it. I have to nearly double heap size to have a successful run.

```
docker run -it --rm -e JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx1027m' memory-eater memory-eater
```

Why is this? I did try setting different levels of docker --memory and --memory-swap but the 1027m heap size is always required.

Additional Info:

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at MemoryEater.main(MemoryEater.java:10)
```

Program:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class MemoryEater
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Vector v = new Vector();
    for( int i=1; i<512; i++)
    {
      byte b[] = new byte[1048576];
      v.add(b);
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      System.out.println( "i = " + i + " free memory: " + rt.freeMemory() + " max memory: " + rt.maxMemory() + " total memory: " + rt.totalMemory() );

    }
    while( true ){}
  }
}
```

Both native and container are 64bit.

Comment: Probably your docker container doesn't have enough memory? How much memory do you *give* to the container?!

Comment: please specify which memory error you get. There are a few and may mean different things.

Comment: Could you add a code example? Are you sure you only allocate 512MB on the target system? Are you sure Java is shutting down here and not docker? Compare https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/ for a common problem with Java exceeding the container's memory limit.

Comment: Both are 64 bit JVMs? Having locally a 32 bit JVM would immediately explain all.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker command I do not see that you are restricting memory usage in any way. That means docker will allow the container to use whatever the host is able to give. With that your JVM will (hopefully) die for memory before docker gets active.

Check out the available options:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

And use `docker stats`to display actual resource usage and limits.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/